# SSIS - Truncate table does not work

Tags: ssis, package, truncate

I have a really weird problem.

I have a SSIS package that transfers data from Oracle Source to an OLE DB destination. The transfer works fine. Before the transfer an SQL task should truncate the destination.

When I right-click the task and select "**Execute Task**" it truncates the table successfully.

When I run the whole SSIS package **the truncate task does not work**. I'm using the right database and the right table. What's wrong? When I manually execute the task it works but when the package runs it won't.

I have no idea why its not working.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: What error are you getting? (Have a look for  in the Progress tab)

Comment: @MiguelH I'm getting no error message at all, thats confusing. Package runs without any errors. The truncate SQL task has this green tick which means : successful.

Comment: So, you're running both the package and the task within visual studio, as the same user (TRUNCATE normally requires extra access privileges, which is why I ask.) And what evidence exactly are you seeing that the truncate isn't working, and how are you gathering it? (Your view of the data may be affected by a transaction; have you pressed the stop button in SSIS before checking, if you're using an external tool to check? I'm not sure when transactions are committed in SSIS, and there may be extra confusion given that TRUNCATE isn't a logged operation.)

Comment: @MattGibson I deployed the package to the SQL server. I tested the task in my visual studio program. Just recognized after the package run, there were more records in the destination table than should be.

Comment: How are you running the deployed package? And is it using a different user for the database connection?

Comment: The package is run by the SQL Server user. And it has full access rights. But now I created the same package again und deployed it. Seems like its working. I don't know what the problem was.

Comment: Install [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com) It's generally a helpful tool but in this scenario, I suspect you will discover that this package has Configurations or Expressions at play. This is resulting in either the SQL Statement changing or the connection manager is pointing to somewhere where you don't expect it or you have not deployed the package/are running a different version of the package via agent. The fact that it works when you started over gives credence to this assumption. Otherwise, you're going to need to post some screenshots of what the package looks like

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the answer, but I had a similar experience. It turned out that my table was repopulating more quickly than I expected, and I was returning more data than I expected. So the truncate worked, but it got masked by the following onslaught of data.